# Appending to a private TextArea from a different class in Java

Tags: java, private

```java
class Backend extends UI {
    // some code
    void start() {
        txtRespond.append(Bot + ": hello, " + Name + "\n"); /* have a problem accessing txtRespond */

public class UI extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    // some code
    private javax.swing.JTextArea txtRespond;
```

I'm trying to add sentences to my `JTextArea` from a different class.

Comment: sub classes can not access `private` fields, mark them `protected` or provide non private methods for mutation of private states

Comment: Design-wise, I doubt you're intending to extend UI from Backend, but rather are just attempting to access methods/etc from UI. You should separate these two classes (as Backend is now a GUI as well) and pass a reference to one of them in the other's constructor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in my comment very initially when you posted the question, You need to have the private field marked as protected so that the sub class can access it or provide methods for mutation.

Second approach is better as it protects the encapsulation.

```
public class UI extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    // some code
    private javax.swing.JTextArea txtRespond;

    protected void appendResponse(String response){
        txtRespond.append(response);
    }

    // your other methods and code if you have.
}


class Backend extends UI {
    // some code
    void start() {
        appendResponse(Bot + ": hello, " + Name + "\n"); 
    }
}
```

Having a class handle the responsibility of modifying its state is a good practice. We should avoid making them non private.

*P.S. if bot, Name are defined in parent class then you can just pass the variant part of the string and pass it to parent method as parameters(of course you need to modify the signature of method to accept more than one string) and in the method defination you can handle the merging of the strings as per requirements.

Comment: Thanks a lot man. Oh yeah ps just a small typo i think it should be txtRespond not txt.Respond eh?

Comment: yes, edited, you can mark the answer as accepted if it was helpful in resolving your issue.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access `private` variable of parent, make the variable `txtRespond` `protected` or create a getter for that variable.

Comment: The problem is that i used JFrame from and i cannot edit the "private javax.swing.JTextArea txtRespond;". Thats the problem. Hmmm